# Change logging directory/file for an Upstart service

Tags: 12.04, upstart

I have an upstart service that it fills up the space. I need to move the logs from /var/log/upstart to a different directory /pub/data/logs/order_server. I tried to do it using

```
console log --logdir /pub/data/logs/order_server
```

but it gives an error

```
start: Unknown job: order_server
```

checking the file

```
$ init-checkconf /etc/init/order_server.conf
ERROR: failed to ask Upstart to check conf file
```

The story is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163216/change-logging-directory-file-for-an-upstart-service). I ended up doing the hack `exec /path/to/my/daemon --arg1 --arg2 >/mnt/log/XYZ 2>&1` as someone suggested.

The following is the service conf file

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/order_server.conf
description "order server dev version"



start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

exec /pub/integration_prod/integration/order_server.sh >> /pub/data/logs/order_server/order_server.log 2>&1
```

Now the log file location is changed to the new location but getting it difficult to rotate the logs. The log file gets zipped up but a new log file is not created.

the upstart rotation looks something like this

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log /pub/data/logs/order_server/order_server.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 3
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
}
```

My initial intention is to fix it by using the **console log** option as suggested [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-log). I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

The cookbook says `--logdir` is a command-line option, which means it's not an option that goes into an upstart job file, but on the command-line of Upstart itself. You can verify this in the init(8) manual page, cf. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/init.8.html

```
   --logdir directory
          Write   job   output   log  files  to  a  directory  other  than
          /var/log/upstart.
```

In other words, it's a global option, not a per-job option.